# MigrationTool is not Moving only Copying

Tags: azure-devops

We have run through the tool on our org but even though it is indeed taking work items from Project A and duplicating them in project B, we are not seeing that the items are being deleted in Project A so for all intents and purposes, we are conducting a "copy" operation. Is there something we are missing in the config file or execution of the tool to perform the "move"? thank you

Here is my config file, I have removed connection related information since it is working properly.

```
{
  "Version": "11.11",
  "LogLevel": "Verbose",
  "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
  "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://xxx/",
    "Project": "Project (From)",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "xxx",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https:xxx",
    "Project": "Project (To)",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId",
    "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "PersonalAccessToken": "xxx",
    "LanguageMaps": {
      "AreaPath": "Area",
      "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
  },
  "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "$type": "TreeToTagMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "toSkip": 3,
      "timeTravel": 1
    }
  ],
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
  "GitRepoMapping": null,
  "Processors": [
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemDeleteConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc"
    },
    //{
    //  "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
    //  "ReplayRevisions": true,
    //  "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
    //  "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
    //  "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
    //  "BuildFieldTable": false,
    //  "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
    //  "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
    //  "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
    //  "Enabled": true,
    //  "LinkMigration": true,
    //  "AttachmentMigration": true,
    //  "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
    //  "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
    //  "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
    //  "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
    //  "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
    //  "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
    //  "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
    //  "CollapseRevisions": false,
    //  "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": true
    //},
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "Enabled": true,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "C:\\Users\\ABCD\\Desktop\\AzureDevOpsMigrationTool\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please include more details: what tool are you using, how is it configured, and a reproducable example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is the config file I am using which is yielding the copy results. I have removed personally identifiable information regarding names and PAT tokens and will be posting shortly, thank you